# Session created after the postback occured and page-load event doesnt use session correctly in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, session, postback, pageload

I’ve made a handy “user control” for login to my website and it is placed in the site master.

The natural procedure is that the user logs in the web site and he should be announced with a welcome message containing its full name. The full-Name naturally should sits in a session variable created when the user logged on.

There is no doubt that we place the desired code in the “page_load” event and expect it to pass user’s full-name to the right circumstances (here its a label named lblFullName) in order to print/show the welcome message when login button clicked, But the  full-name doesn’t passed until the user logs in the website again (for the 2nd times).

Why this problem happens?

Its some part of my code:

> ```
>     protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
>     {
>         if (Session["FullName"]==null)
>         {
>            //nothing 2 do.
>         }
>         else
>         {
>             lblFullName.Text = Session["FullName"].ToString();
>         }
>     }
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably set the Session variable in the user control after the `Page_Load` event has been processed, so that it will not see the user name until the next postback.

In order to update the Label text as soon as the login is validated, you could:

1. Define an event in the user control
2. Register an event handler in the main page
3. Call the event handler as soon as the user has logged in
4. In the event handler, update the Label text

You could also eliminate the `Session` variable by passing the user full name in an `EventArgs` derived class. If you make the following class accessible in the user control and in the main form:

```
public class StringEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public StringEventArgs(string value)
    {
       Value = value;
    }
}
```

then you can define this event in the user control:

```
public event EventHandler<StringEventArgs> UserLoggedIn;
```

In the function where the login is confirmed, you call the event handlers:

```
private void UserLoginValidation()
{
    // Login validation is done here
    bool loginSuccessful = ...

    if (loginSuccessful && UserLoggedIn != null)
    {
        UserLoggedIn(this, new StringEventArgs(fullName));
    }
}
```

In the main page, you register the event handler, which updates the Label:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    loginUserControl1.UserLoggedIn += loginUserControl1_UserLoggedIn;
    ...
}

private void loginUserControl1_UserLoggedIn(object sender, StringEventArgs e)
{
    lblFullName.Text = e.Value;
}
```

Comment: I followed the solution, It works correctly. thanks a lot.

Comment: But since i am new to ASP.NET and C# environment, i could not exactly understand what is happened. Is there a more simple way using the same session concept?

Comment: Yes, you could use the session variable. However, it would not be as clean as my solution. Passing the value as a function argument is better than using a session variable. Global variables should only be used when other solutions don't work. In any case, you could: (1) Not create `StringEventArgs`, (2) Replace `UserLoggedIn(this, new StringEventArgs(fullName));` by `Session["FullName"] = fullName; UserLoggedIn(this, EventArgs.Empty);`, (3) Replace `lblFullName.Text = e.Value;` by `lblFullName.Text = (string)Session["FullName"];` (and use `EventArgs` instead of `StringEventArgs`).

Comment: If you want to learn more about Custom Events, you can see this article: http://www.akadia.com/services/dotnet_user_controls.html. It may even give you more ideas since they demonstrate the use of these events in a... login validation user control. :-)